# Using JSP Custom Rule in PMD

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd

I need a kind of validation to use on Sonar, which should look over JSF elements in XHTML pages verifying if the input elements contains ID attribute. (example:  )

Initially I'm trying to do it using PMD.
As I've seen PMD can interpret JSP pages. Is it correct?
The way to do it is implementing a custom rule based on AbstractJspRule.

The problem so far it that PMD tries to parse XHTML page as Java code. It should interpret as JSP page.

My codes:
class:

```
public class TestXhtmlRule extends AbstractJspRule {

 @Override
 public Object visit(final ASTElement node, final Object data) {
      // ...
 }

 @Override
 public Object visit(final ASTAttribute node, final Object data) {
      // ...
 }

}
```

xml:

```
<ruleset name="Basic JSF rules" 
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <include-pattern>**/*.xhtml</include-pattern>

<rule name="idsJSF" language="jsp"  
        message="..."
        class="pmd.rule.TestXhtmlRule">
        <description>
            ...
        </description>
        <priority>3</priority>

        <example>
        <![CDATA[
             <h:inputText id="itNome" label="Nome" value="#{pessoaBean.nome}" />;
        ]]>
        </example>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

The error from log:

```
[pmd] net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ParseException: Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "abstract" ...
    "class" ...
    "final" ...
    "import" ...
    "interface" ...
    "native" ...
    "private" ...
    "protected" ...
    "public" ...
    "static" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    ";" ...
    "@" ...
    "\u001a" ...
    "~[]" ...
    "@" ...
    "@" ...
    "@" ...

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParser.generateParseException(JavaParser.java:9867)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParser.jj_consume_token(JavaParser.java:9751)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParser.CompilationUnit(JavaParser.java:190)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaParser.parse(AbstractJavaParser.java:56)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.parse(SourceCodeProcessor.java:90)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:136)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:75)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable.call(PmdRunnable.java:75)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable.call(PmdRunnable.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I make it work?
Would be easier to verify this rule with checkstyle instead of PMD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I've seen PMD can interpret JSP pages. Is it correct?

Yes, but only if you have wellformed XHTML - which you do.

> How can I make it work?

The problem is happening before PMD even runs your rule.  It parses the files (whether Java or jsp or anything else) into an AST (abstract syntax tree) and then runs the relevant rules against it.  Are you passing the -jsp flag when running PMD as described in the how to use it section [at the bottom of the PMD JSP page](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.3/jspsupport.html)?  My guess is that you aren't so PMD treats everything as Java.

Comment: Humm, you may be right. I've missing the '-jsp'. Now I'll just try to find out how to use this param with Ant. I forgot to specify in the question, but I'm using Ant PMD task to run it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a way to do it with the Ant task.  However, you can use the Ant exec task to run PMD as a command line.  Then you pass in the arguments as a command line and don't need custom support.

Comment: I didn't get to run it yet, but I'll have to leave it for while and work on other demand. So I'll accept this answer as I think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Sonar Web Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Plugin)? It should allow you to check for IDs on tags for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look on this.
But if possible I prefer PMD, once we already have some rules (for java) implemented using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug (or missed feature) in PMD. Source file language is determined by file name only. `*.xml` files assumed to be in xml language, `*.jsp` files - jsp language. `xhtml` extension is not specified explicitly, so `*.xhtml` files default to be java language, and are parsed by Java parser.

Here is current extension to language mapping (hardcoded in PMD):
https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/Language.java?source=cc

Here is feature request to make it configurable:
http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/feature-requests/568/